# new user compiling?

Tags: compiling, svn

so this is my first time trying to compile a source code... I downloaded subversion (no problems), added the svn repositry (with no directory(facepalm)) using code

```
svn checkout http://svn.gib.me/public/borderlands2/trunk/
```

and it seems to have worked (no error messages files all look good) but i don't know what to do next... i read all the compiling threads i say on here and they all say read the read me and then try it out... if someone could look at it and explain it to me i would apriciate it... i don't like asking for help or failing and its looking like both right now...

sorry don't know if i should of added it in the first place but the program i want is gibbed borderlands 2 save editor... i can't tell if theres more then one program there or not... also i know the program was made for windows but i belive thats what source codes are for is to use them on opensource software...(hopefully)

Answer (score 0):

This particular software appears to be written for Windows.  The [readme.txt](http://svn.gib.me/public/borderlands2/trunk/readme.txt) file says:

> SaveEdit requires the full .NET Framework 4, which can be downloaded
>   from   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851
>
> Most UI interface icons are courtesy of Fugue Icons available at
>   http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/

It may be possible to build and run the software with Mono which you can run on Ubuntu, the above says it needs .NET Framework 4 and the [Mono compatibility list](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) seems to imply this should work.

However, the build system that's included in the file is a solution file for Visual Studio 2010 (that's what the `Borderlands 2.sln` file is in your checkout).

I don't know of any way to build a solution file without Visual Studio itself, so I think you'd have to figure out how to build it yourself.

Unless you're in for a lot of work I'd suggest building this on Windows with a copy of [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) (free).